# Sequelize: filter table by hassMany associations fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have problem to find and filter data from hasMany associations fields, am using following packages version:
"sequelize": "^6.9.0",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3-rc.0"

This is my tables:

```
const RequestForm = sequelize.define('RequestForm', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        noUpdate : true
    },
   type: DataTypes.STRING

})


const RequestStatus = sequelize.define('RequestStatus', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        noUpdate : true
    },
})



const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        noUpdate : true
    }})
```

This is associations:

```
    RequestStatus.belongsTo(RequestForm);
    RequestForm.hasMany(RequestStatus);

    RequestStatus.belongsTo(Employee);
    Employee.hasMany(RequestStatus);
```

I am trying to find RequestForm data that have one of following condition:

1. RequestForm type = "One"
2. RequestForm type = "Two"
3. one of RequestStatus EmployeeId(FK) equal to "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000"

and i want return all RequestStatus of RequestForm, so i can't but where in include

---

This My code but not working and get error ->   original: Error: Unknown column 'RequestStatus.EmployeeId' in 'where clause'

```
RequestForm.find({
where: {
 [Op.or]: [
        {type: {[Op.in]: ["One", "Two"]}},
        {
                employee_id_value: Sequelize.where(
                    Sequelize.col("RequestStatuses.EmployeeId"),
                    {
                        [Op.eq]: "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000",
                    }
                )
            },
]
},
include:[
        {
            model: RequestStatus,
                attributes: ['id', 'EmployeeId'],
            required: false,
        },
        {Other Models}
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `RequestStatus` in `Sequelize.col` and you don't need to indicate `employee_id_value` field, use `Sequelize.where` directly:

```js
where: {
 [Op.or]: [
        {
          type: {
            [Op.in]: ["One", "Two"]
          }
        },
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("RequestStatus.EmployeeId"),
          Op.eq, "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000")
 ]
},
```

Comment: not working also

Comment: What error message did you get this time?